# Can there be variations on the Witch of Agnesi?

Tags: functions, parametric

The function known as "The Witch of Agnesi" can be constructed using a circle of radius $a$, and is written in Cartesian coordinates as
$$f(x)=\frac{8a^3}{x^2+4a^2}$$
The family of functions that follow this pattern are all dependent upon the circle, which gives it its "bump" shape. Can the function be modified so the circle is replaced by an ellipse with unequal major and minor axis? How would it be parameterized, and written in Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: [Here is a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_of_Agnesi).

Comment: @TonyK I had been there, but I hadn't gotten much out of it.

Comment: Yes, but others might like to know what you are talking about.

Comment: @TonyK Okay, true. I had disregarded that because it shows up early on a search-engine search, but a link here is more convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a circle of radius $a$, suppose we start with an ellipse with horizontal semi-axis $a$, and vertical semi-axis $b$. Then the construction is identical, except that everything is stretched by a factor of $b/a$ in the vertical direction. So the equation is simply

$$f(x)=\frac{b}{a}\cdot\frac{8a^3}{x^2+4a^2} = \frac{8a^2b}{x^2+4a^2}$$

Comment: . . . Which of course reduces to a circle for the case $a = b$. Thanks. I'll wait to see if there are any other answers before accepting, but this looks like it will work.

Comment: I have swapped $a$ and $b$ now, to make it even simpler.

Comment: Even better. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I plotted TonyK's result with *Mathematica*.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
a = 1; 
b = 0.5;
ContourPlot[{8*a^2*b/(4*a^2 + x^2) - y == 
   0, (x/a)^2 + (y/b - 1)^2 - 1 == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```